# Android : Need Regex for complex String

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching, grammar

I have String

```
String myData = "status:\" op en \" AND \"Managed Type\":\"El ectrical\" AND status:verified status:\"resolved\" OR Managed Type:\"Ci vil\"";
```

I need to distinct all values and attributes from the string.

I have tried one regex with pattern which fulfill requirement as some level , but need help for complex parsing

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
                "\\s*[OR|AND]?\\s*(\"?[[\\s*]?\\w*[\\s*]?]*\"?)\\:\"?(([\\s*\\(\\)<>/\\\\\\$\\=\\#\\+%^'`&!{}:;|\\?\\*\\.\\[\\],~@-]?\\w*[\\(\\)<>/\\\\\\$\\=\\#\\+%^'`&!{}:;|\\?\\*\\.\\[\\],~@-]?\\s*)*)\"?\\s*[OR|AND]?\\s*",
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " : " + matcher.group(2));
        }
```

OutPut is like that

```
status :  op en 
"Managed Type" : El ectrical
D status : verified status:
" OR Managed Type : Ci vil
```

Accepted result

```
status :  op en 
"Managed Type" : El ectrical
status : verified 
status: resolved
Managed Type : Ci vil
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: When your regex looks like an [backslash hell](https://tudorbarbu.ninja/backslash-hell/), it is time to reconsider your approach.

Comment: I feel that you might want to lean towards using a parser rather than a regex.

Comment: Why is `status:verified status:\"resolved\"` not separated by an AND/OR? Is that valid?

Comment: @Biffen I have gone through that link a long time ago. and i learnt a lot from that and tried this but don't get success. If you help me out for this issue will be greatful .. thanks.

Comment: @Michael, Because this is not compulsory to add `AND`,`OR`  in string

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I tried following regular expression string which is working fine (please note that I tried in iOS):

```
NSString *regExPattern = @"(\\w*|\"[\\w\\s]{1,}\"):(\"[\\w\\s]{1,}\"?|\\w*)";
```